# Cant retrive Custom Properties from CmisObject (Documentum)

Tags: java, cmis, documentum, opencmis, ecm

I am trying to retrive all properties from CmisObject but I cant see the custom defined properties which are present in Documentum system.

```
Document sourceDocument = (Document)getCmisObject(sourceSession, sourceObjectId);

Iterator<Property<?>> propertie =  sourceDocument.getProperties().iterator();
while(propertie.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("Display Name:"+propertie.next().getDisplayName());
    System.out.println("Value:"+propertie.next().getValue().toString());
}
```

I tried above code . I also tried

```
Map<String, Object> properties = CMISHelper.objectProperties(sourceDocument);
```

But coulden't get all custom properties which are present in Documentum system.

Comment: Have you set a property filter in the operation context that selects your properties? See https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/operation-context/index.html#property-filter

Comment: Florian Müller Thanks it worked. Now i am little confused as i used same code to retrive custom properties(Source of Document object was Alfresco)  and it worked fine but I just changed Source to Documentum and faced above problem.

Comment: you're using `next()` twice in a single loop

Comment: Kalebere, please post an answer explaining how you solved the problem, thanks!